# How can I differentiate users other than through IP address for a shoutbox application?

Tags: session, cookies, ip-address

I'm coding in php, jQuery, and AJAX to create a shoutbox application. So far I'm recording different users through their IP address so as to assign different default usernames and to store user-selected usernames according to their appropriate IP address. (the shoutbox is not login-based and assigns an automatic guest username on first sign-in when visiting the website and the user can change this default guest username to something else)

The problem is that when there are multiple people from the same network using the same IP address, my shoutbox won't be able to differentiate between the users on the different computers. Is there a way to differentiate between IPs under the same network? Or if I use a PHP session or cookie, will that solve the problem too? The main thing is I want to be able to store the user-created usernames in the appropriate computers so the user is not presented with the default guest username next time he or she visits my shoutbox webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can write their usernames to cookies. So they’ll connect with the same username until their cookie files expire, or they reinstall their browser (or OS), or clear the browser data, or simply use another computer.

Or, if it’s okay to keep the usernames in a database, you can also differ users by IP plus some headers from browsers (for example, the user agent). Of course, in this case the username remains the same until the user updates or reconfigures the browser, or uses another browser or another computer. Or if his or her IP changes (a lot of ISPs use dynamic IPs, and also the user can connect from a café via Wi-Fi, for example)

You can also combine these ways. For example, save the username to cookies, and at the same time, save the same username to the server with IP and user agent. If a cookie is available, use the username from the cookie. If it’s not, try to recover the person’s username from the database using his IP and user agent. Even if that wasn’t accurate and you assigned a wrong username, the user still can change it to the proper one.

Answer (score 2):

You could assign an id to each ip-address. So the first person will be assigned id=1. The second with the same ip-address, id=2, and so on.

Comment: how would i know the second instance of the same ip is the same person or a different person?

Answer (score 2):

1. Check the HTTP header for 'X-FORWARDED-FOR' which is set by firewall proxies to identify the IP address of the individual on the other side. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For
2. Check for a specific cookie on their computer, and if there isn't one present then they're a different user (although, of course, they may have just cleared their cookies out)